# FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout - Azure App Service

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, fastcgi

im working on a python/flask website on Azure which connects to a ms sql db. Some requests produce the following error:

*D:\home\python361x64\python.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout*

I assume that this is a timeout problem but i cant find a way to configure the request time out on Azure. Does anybody have an advice? Thank you very much :-)

Regards
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it's about fastcgi activity timeout settings instead of syntax error because of the same code works sometimes and sometimes not.

You could try to upload an `applicationHost.xdt` file to path: `D:\home\site\applicationHost.xdt`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <fastCgi>
      <application xdt:Locator="Match(fullPath)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(activityTimeout)"
            fullPath="D:\home\python361x64\python.exe" activityTimeout="600"/>
    </fastCgi>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

More details ,please refer to this [doc](http://www.slowtick.com/pages/az-appgw-timeouts).

Of course, you could focus on the root, optimize the database query scheme.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you very much. i could not solve the problem with activityTimeout setting. i optimized all my db queries and the db itself so that the timeout does not occure anymore.

Comment: @chrigi yes, i think optimizing db queries and setting activityTimeout are both solutions against the timeout issue.I already updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the script above no longer works. use this extension in azure (it auto generates)
  https://github.com/shibayan/IISManager

if you cant then this script:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <fastCgi>
      <application fullPath="D:\Python27\python.exe" xdt:Locator="Match(fullPath)" activityTimeout="900" requestTimeout="601" instanceMaxRequests="10000" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(activityTimeout,requestTimeout,instanceMaxRequests)" />
      <application fullPath="D:\Python34\python.exe" xdt:Locator="Match(fullPath)" maxInstances="4" activityTimeout="900" requestTimeout="601" instanceMaxRequests="10000" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(maxInstances,activityTimeout,requestTimeout,instanceMaxRequests)" />
    </fastCgi>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

place this file in site folder

after that restart the app from the portal(necessary)